# No WAN connection until I boot a specific PC

Tags: networking, router, internet, lan

I have limited networking experience, just basic.

My setup is as follows:

1. Entry point is my ISP's ONT providing the Internet connection through PPPoE
2. An Asus router plugged in the first port of the ONT
3. All router ports plugged with GB patches that go everywhere in my home
4. A second Asus router as repeater in one of the rooms, plugged in one of the four ports of the first router.

I have various devices, but my case seems to be related to one of the PCs plugged in the network:

- Main PC plugged in the second router (the repeater)
- A PC wired fro ma room to one of the first router ports.

The issue happened twice so far, once a month.

At some point there is no Internet, the main router can't connect to the WAN. To me, ASUS behave strange, although they've confirmed is by design. When there is no Internet, the LAN is not properly initialized, so no IPs in LAN, can't access the devices in the network. Besides this, there is no way to make it connect.

I have tried each time to connect directly to ONT, establish the connection to the Internet. Here comes the weirdiness:

- Using Windows 10 it can establish a connection by configuring a PPPoE connection under Windows.
- Using Linux (Gentoo based) or the router, it never works.

At this point, the second PC - the one wired in the main router - is OFF. At the moment I boot it (under Linux) the WAN connection starts to work on the router, all the network is back and works for a long time even with the PC in question OFF. It does not matter if the router restarts, the network will be fine until next time (happened twice so far, once a month, or 40 days).

What can be the reason, what can I do to find the problem source?

Comment: Have you updated the firmware of all the routers (including the ISP's) to the latest version?

Comment: Not ISP's, I have no possibility, but they confirmed it's OK. I've even reset mine to factory and setup from scratch, just to confirm it's them or not.

Comment: Is the ISP's router the DHCP server for the local network? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc, My first router is the DHCP, I have no access to the ONT admin UI. It just serves Internet and TV.

Comment: Have you tried to reboot routers when this happened?

Comment: @harrymc, I've rebooted the ONT, the routers, the computer, wired to the main router directly and tried to establish a PPPoE connection with a Linux and a Windows. Windows succeeded only. Did not see the second PC effect in the first place. That is a simple Linux system , not a server of some kind.

Comment: Last attempt to get a handle on the problem : Do all computers use a dynamic IP, or is there also one/some that have static IP? Do you have neighbors that might steal the network by duplicate SSID or other interference (or similar ONT modem)?

Comment: All devices have a static IP by their MAC, the ONT has no WiFi, Wifi is on the routers only. All devices that access the WiFi are doing this by a whitelist. I can't tell if my neighbors have such abilities, I did not notice. This happened twice, at 30-40 days and the second PC seems to reset or fix something in my network.

Comment: I can't think of anything else except external interference. Too weird.

Comment: Indeed, too weird. The ISP team replaced my ONT PSU, thinking it may introduce instability, but why Windows connected (twice)?

Comment: I'm fresh out of ideas. If nobody else comes up with some idea, you might just have to live with it.